# How to pass variable from URL to DBcontroller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm new in Laravel and I tried this:

**Router**

```
Route::get('productdetails/{id}', function($id){
'ProductDetailsController@productdetails' .$id;
```

});

**ProductDetailsController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ProductDetailsController extends Controller
{
    public function inventory(){
    $inventory = DB::select('select * FROM inventory WHERE barcode = ?', [$id]);;
    return view('productdetails',['inventory'=>$inventory]);
    }
}
```

and I got:

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Comment: Are you trying to call the inventory method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct syntax for route is:

```
Route::get('productdetails/{id}', 'ProductDetailsController@inventory');
```

And method should look like this:

```
public function inventory($id)
{
    ....
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#basic-routing